# Javascript button deleting entire table, Should only delete the row its created with

Tags: javascript

I have a table being created on submission of a form. The button that gets created with the table row should only delete that row, instead its deleting the entire table. I've tried changing the target of the button but the only way I get it to work is to have it target the parent element. I created a function for the delete button that targets the parent element.

```
function userData(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const type = payment.value;
  const paid = amountPaid.value;
  const item = itemPurchased.value;
  const date = datePurchased.value;
  const deleteRow = document.createElement('button');
  deleteRow.setAttribute('id', 'deleteButton');
  deleteRow.textContent = 'Delete';
  deleteRow.addEventListener('click', deleteExpenseRow);
  const tableData = document.getElementById("table-body");
  let newRow = `
    <tr>
      <td>${type}</td>
      <td>${`$ ${paid}`}</td>
      <td>${item}</td>
      <td>${date}</td>
    </tr>
`

  if (type !== 'Select Payment' || date !== '' || paid !== '' || item !== '') {
    tableData.innerHTML += newRow;
    tableData.appendChild(deleteRow);
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', resetForm());
  } else {
    alert('Please enter an expense');
  }
}
```

```
function deleteExpenseRow(e) {
  let deleteData = e.target.parentElement;
  deleteData.remove();
}
```

Comment: What is `deleteExpenseRow` function?

Comment: added the deleteExpenseRow function

Comment: Your existing markup won't be valid. A button cannot be a child of a `<table>` or `<tbody>`. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you should use closest('tr'). For example:

```
<tr>
<td>col 1 data</td>
<td>col 2 data</td>
<td> <button onclick="delrow()"> </td>
</tr>

function delrow() {
    var therow = this.event.target.closest('tr');
    var col1 = therow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    var col2 = therow.cells[1].innerHTML;
}
```